# How do I run dnscmd via ssh?

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I am looking for a working solution that would allow me to run dnscmd and other similar commands that do require you to logged in into a domain via SSH, so I can execute them freely from my machine (which is obviously not a Windows one).

I already configured Cygwin, cygwin-ssh and joined the domain and I was able to login using SSH with my domain account, by using the `user+domain@machine` notation.

Still, when I try to perform operations I do get:

`DNS Server failed to enumerate records for node @.
    Status = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED     5  (0x00000005)`

I suspect that the reason for this is due to the fact that the cygwin SSH sessions do run as a local service account and not as my domain user account.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That is possible, it is also possible UAC is a problem. Does cygwin-ssh provide a "run as administrator" option?

Comment: you could try winrm with pywinrm and wsmancmd.py (Look here for a writeup: http://www.cloudbase.it/windows-without-passwords-in-openstack/). Then you can do something like this: ./wsmancmd.py -U http://host:5985/wsman -u Administrator -p pwd 'shutdown /s /t 0' (bonus points if you configure tls and even certificate based authentication). Or you can enable telnet  server (don't) in the windows host.